# How to update content of SimpleWalkerList in Urwid?

Tags: python, urwid

I cant find a proper way to update the content of the SimpleWalkerList in URWID. Below is simplified example of the code I am trying to generate list base on the user input:

```
    import urwid

palette = [('header', 'white', 'black'),
    ('reveal focus', 'black', 'dark cyan', 'standout')]

items = [urwid.Text("foo"),
         urwid.Text("bar"),
         urwid.Text("baz")]

content = urwid.SimpleListWalker([
    urwid.AttrMap(w, None, 'reveal focus') for w in items])

listbox = urwid.ListBox(content)

show_key = urwid.Text("Press any key", wrap='clip')
head = urwid.AttrMap(show_key, 'header')
top = urwid.Frame(listbox, head)

def show_all_input(input, raw):

    show_key.set_text("Pressed: " + " ".join([
        unicode(i) for i in input]))
    return input


def exit_on_cr(input):
    if input in ('q', 'Q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
    elif input == 'up':
        focus_widget, idx = listbox.get_focus()
        if idx > 0:
            idx = idx-1
            listbox.set_focus(idx)
    elif input == 'down':
        focus_widget, idx = listbox.get_focus()
        idx = idx+1
        listbox.set_focus(idx)
    elif input == 'enter':
        pass
    # 
    #how here can I change value of the items list  and display the ne value????
    #
def out(s):
    show_key.set_text(str(s))


loop = urwid.MainLoop(top, palette,
    input_filter=show_all_input, unhandled_input=exit_on_cr)
loop.run()
```

Expected result would be changing the value for example from 'foo' to 'oof' (so simple string manipulation). 
Whatever way I am using is not allowing me to manipulate on the values. Do I need to brake the loop and redraw the entire screen from scratch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC (I haven't used Urwid in a long time), not being able to update on the fly is part of what makes `SimpleListWalker` "simple", and if you want do that, you use one of the other list walker classes or write your own.

Comment: I think one of them lets you update it just by modifying the list that you originally passed in, without having to call anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the docs for [`SimpleListWalker`](http://urwid.org/reference/list_walkers.html#urwid.SimpleListWalker):

> contents – list to copy into this object
>
> Changes made to this object (when it is treated as a list) are detected automatically and will cause ListBox objects using this list walker to be updated.

So, all you have to do is modify the elements in the list:

```
elif input in 'rR':
    _, idx = listbox.get_focus()
    am = content[idx].original_widget
    am.set_text(am.text[::-1])
```

Even if you had immutable values in the list, you could just replace them with new objects:

```
elif input in 'rR':
    _, idx = listbox.get_focus()
    w = urwid.Text(content[idx].original_widget.text[::-1])
    content[idx] = urwid.AttrMap(w, None, 'reveal focus')
```

But since you don't have any immutable objects getting in the way, that isn't necessary; the first version will work fine.

Either way, if you press `r`, whatever text you were pointing at gets reversed, like `foo` to `oof`. (Of course if you were using any markup, you'd need to do something a bit more careful than that, but you're not.)